# Match pair for keyof and valueof an interface

Tags: typescript

I have an interface like this:

```
interface ISession {
    emailAddress: string;
    me: IUser | null;
    groups: IGroup[] | null;
}
```

I want to create a an object with this pseudo-code:

```
type SetAction = {
    type: typeof SET,
    key: K in keyof ISession,
    value: V in valueof ISession
};
```

The problem with this pseudocode is it does not ensure that the value type matches the value of `ISession[k]`.

Is this possible in TS?

A similar problem I had to this, this is not apart of the question, but to help others maybe think, because i feel the solution would be the same. I need to write a function `function set(key, value)`. Where the `key` and `value` are of the approprate matching pair.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create such a type but what you want to do is create a union of all possible `key`/`value` combinations. So the type we want to create is:

```
type SetAction  = 
    { type: typeof SET, key: 'emailAddress', value: string; } |
    { type: typeof SET, key: 'me', value:  IUser | null; } |
    { type: typeof SET, key: 'groups', value: IGroup[] | null; }
```

We can do this by using a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)

```
type SetAction = keyof ISession extends infer K ? // introduce type parameter 
    K extends keyof ISession ? // distribute over the type parameter 
        { type: typeof SET, key: K, value: ISession[K]; } // The type that we construct for each K
    : never: never
```

Or a perfhaps simpler to understand version using mapped types (the result is the same):

```
type SetAction = {
    [K in keyof ISession]-?: { type: typeof SET, key: K, value: ISession[K]; } 
}[keyof ISession]
```

Comment: Holy moly, I posted this originally thinking it wasn't possible. But this got answered within minutes of asking and it is possible. This is seriously really cool! Stackoverflow is blocking me from accepting your answer for another 4 minutes, will accept it soon. This is super awesome learning, I'm going to try to apply this to the function arguments as well, do you think the same technique would apply?

Comment: @Noitidart depends on what you are trying to do, if you have sample code, post another question, I am usually just as quick ;)

Comment: Thanks Titiation for such fast replies, and the edit to the solution, it is fantastic for learning! I was trying to create apply this technique to this pseudo-code `function set(key: K in keyof ISession, value: ISession[K]): SetAction`.

Comment: @Noitidart You just need a type parameter there `function set<K extends keyof ISession>(key: K, value: ISession[K]): SetAction`. For types we need to spell out all possibilities because no inference happens if we specify the type of a variable. If on the other hand we have a function to play with we can do a lot more since inference kicks in for  type parameters